# Connect two points with a line in R

Tags: r, connect, lines, points

I have a problem connecting two points with the same y value. My dataset looks like this *(I hope the formatting is ok)*:

```
attackerip,min,max
125.88.146.123,2016-03-29 17:38:17.949778,2016-03-30 07:28:47.912983
58.218.205.101,2016-04-05 15:53:20.69986,2016-05-12 17:32:08.583255
183.3.202.195,2016-04-05 15:58:27.862509,2016-04-15 18:15:13.117774
58.218.199.166,2016-04-05 16:09:34.448588,2016-04-24 06:02:12.237922
58.218.204.107,2016-04-05 16:57:17.624509,2016-05-31 00:52:44.007908
```

What I have so far is the following:

```
mydata = read.csv("timeline.csv", sep=',')
mydata$min <- strptime(as.character(mydata$min), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
mydata$max <- strptime(as.character(mydata$max), format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
plot(mydata$min, mydata$attackerip, col="red")
points(mydata$max, mydata$attackerip, col="blue")
```

Which results in: [image: this Plot]

Now I want to connect the points with the same y-axis value. And can not get lines or abline to work. Thanks in Advance!

EDIT: dput of data

```
dput(mydata)
structure(list(attackerip = structure(c(1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("125.88.146.123", 
"183.3.202.195", "58.218.199.166", "58.218.204.107", "58.218.205.101"
), class = "factor"), min = structure(1:5, .Label = c("2016-03-29 17:38:17.949778", 
"2016-04-05 15:53:20.69986", "2016-04-05 15:58:27.862509", "2016-04-05 16:09:34.448588", 
"2016-04-05 16:57:17.624509"), class = "factor"), max = structure(c(1L, 
4L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("2016-03-30 07:28:47.912983", "2016-04-15 18:15:13.117774", 
"2016-04-24 06:02:12.237922", "2016-05-12 17:32:08.583255", "2016-05-31 00:52:44.007908"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("attackerip", "min", "max"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Final Edit:

The reason why plotting lines did not work was, that the datatype of min and max was timestamps. Casting those to numeric values yielded the expected result. Thanks for your help everyone

Comment: Will edit it in but that looks even worse.

Answer (score 3):

The `lines` function should work just fine. However, you will need to call it for every pair (or set) of points that share the same y value. Here is a reproducible example:

```
# get sets of observations with the same y value
dupeVals <- unique(y[duplicated(y) | duplicated(y, fromLast=T)])
# put the corresponding indices into a list
dupesList <- lapply(dupeVals, function(i) which(y == i))

# scatter plot
plot(x, y)
# plot the lines using sapply
sapply(dupesList, function(i) lines(x[i], y[i]))
```

This returns

[image]

**data**

```
set.seed(1234)
x <- sort(5* runif(30))
y <- sample(25, 30, replace=T)
```

---

As it appears that you have two separate groups for which you would like draw these lines, the following would be the algorithm:

1. for each group, (min and max, I believe)

   - calculate the duplicate values of the y variable
   - put the indicies of these duplicates into a dupesList (maybe dupesListMin and dupesListMax).
2. plot the points
3. run one `sapply` function on each dupesList.

Comment: I need to connect `x1 <- mydata$min,y` and `x2<-mydata$max,y` how would I do that? Thanks for the help !

Comment: You will want to go through the process of collecting the indices of the y values that match as I did in dupesList twice, once for both the min and the max variables. Once these indices are collected into two separate lists, use `sapply` to draw the lines on top of the scatter plot. You will probably want to add the col argument to control the colors.

Comment: I am afraid, I do not know enough about R to actually do that. I assume I have to create two dupesLists and then sapply twice? If I understand it correctly dupeVals is a list of all y values. dupesList is then creating a list of all x values who have duplicate y values. sapply is then calling lines on all x and all duplicate y values. I just do not understand how it calculates the x values.

Comment: I'll add an addendum to my answer.

Comment: It is even easier. min and max are from the same dataset. Y is always an IP-Address. Each Ip-Address is guaranteed to have two x values at the same position. So the Pseudocode would be: `for i <= length(data$min) do drawLine(\[min,i\], \[max, i\]`